# Fastest and most reliable factorization method

Tags: algorithm, math

Which is the fastest and most reliable factorization method used now a days ? I have gone thru
Fermat's Factorization and Pollard's rho factorization method and was wondering are there any better methods to code and implement ?

Comment: For how big of a number? The fastest known for really large numbers is the General Number Field Sieve, but it only becomes the fastest for numbers around 110 digits or larger. The next step down for somewhat smaller numbers would be the Multiple Polynomial Quadratic Sieve.

Comment: Actually I wanted to know about numbers less than 100 digits .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check the Wikipedia article. It has almost everything you want to find: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

The solution really depends on the range of the number, and sometimes the property of the number.

For big number around or less than 100 digits, according to Wikipedia, quadratic sieve is the best. For larger numbers, general number field sieve is better.

I don't talk about small cases, as you are already mentioning Pollard's rho, this should be trivial.